# Paypal incorrect discount and tax values

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, paypal-express, paypal-payments-pro

I've been wrangling with an issue regarding Paypal Pro and Express and was wondering if I'm being stupid or there is a bug.

My cart is showing the correct values but when Paypal displays the amount a user has to pay it is incorrect and is causing IPN values of suspected fraud with Paypal Pro.

Expected Result:
Paypal figures should match the cart page

- Subtotal £249.99
- Discount -£25.00
- VAT £37.50
- **Grand Total £224.99**

Actual Result:
Paypal Express

- Item Total £183.32
- VAT £41.67
- **Grand Total £224.99**

Paypal Pro

- Subtotal £208.32
- VAT £37.50
- Discount £25
- **Grand Total £220.82**

Here are my tax settings [image: VAT Settings]

The store is built on CE 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue if you set Transfer line cart items to no for express checkout only the total should get passed to paypal from your website and paypal wont be doing any extra tax calculations and do the same for paypal pro. Though this option is not available for pro host solution.

What is happening is that paypal is working out the vat from £249.99
which is £41.67 instead of working out the vat after the discount of £25 has been applied.
What it should do is
£249.99 - £25 = 224.99 
 remove uk vat at 20% £37.50 = £187.49

What appears to happens
£249.99 - 41.67(vat at 20% of £249.99) (paypal calulates this)
£208.32 - £25 = £183.32
£183.32 + £37.50 (vat passed from magento to paypal) = £220.82